# CodeIgniter Error After Changing PHP from 5.6 to 7.0 on HostGator via SSH

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3, php-7

So as the title describe, I am receiving this error right now on my CI after changing the PHP from 5.6 to 7.0. It works fine if I revert back to 5.6 but I need my server to be on 7.0.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: SourceGuardian: Unable to initialize module Module compiled with module API=20121212 PHP compiled with module API=20151012 These options need to match

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

Answer (score 0):

From my 2013 blog post: https://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/manually-compiling-php-modules-successfully/

This look familiar?

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcached: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
```

I don’t know about you, but i like to be up to date! My PHP is on 5.5, and I had to install some modules. But sometimes, old versions can rear their ugly head, and cause all manner of grief. Package managers do a good job to take care of all this for you, but sometimes they just don’t work. Leaving you to compile yourself! So lets do it! I’m going to install memcached, and then the imagick libraries (now i know what i’m doing!)

I’m doing this on a CentOS 6 server, but as we are doing the old skool way of compiling etc, this should work on any other flavour of Linux, or indeed Mac OS X.

First step is to download your .tar.gz  then unzip it with tar -zxvf file.tar.gz and change into the folder.

Bring up a web page displaying your servers php.ini. You are looking for the version of PHP API, and the extension_dir.

In your terminal, cd into the module source code folder, and type phpize.

If when you check the API versions , they are different from your php.ini, then an old version of php is being used in the terminal, and your module will not work! In this case, you need to get it to use the correct phpize.

type `which phpize` to find out where the offending file is. (mine was /usr/bin/phpize)

My PHP appeared to be in /usr/local, so I tried running `/usr/local/phpize`. The API’s matched. So then I did the following:

```
mv /usr/bin/phpize /usr/bin/phpize-old
ln -s /usr/local/bin/phpize /usr/bin/phpize
```

Half way there! We need to do the same for php-config

```
 mv /usr/bin/php-config /usr/bin/php-config-old
 ln -s /usr/local/bin/php-config /usr/bin/php-config
```

Now you have done that, installation should be trivial, and work as per loads of tutorial/instrruction pages on the web.

```
./configure
 make
 make install
```

Finally edit your php.ini and add ‘extension = memcached.so’ (or whatever module you compiled), and restart your apache server!

> EDIT : you may need to run ‘phpize –clean’ if it is still compiling with the older stuff from within the modules source folder

Comment: Do you have any idea on how can I access those paths? According to my hosting provider, it is located at /usr/local/bin/php [(SOURCE)](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/linux-application-paths-what-is-the-path-to)

But I can only seem to access anything under the /home path instead of /usr due to access denied. I'll try to contact the host provider on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Download latest SourceGuardian module, which support PHP 7.X:
https://www.sourceguardian.com/loaders/download.php